# White space in between top and content divs

Tags: html, css

I've set all my `divs` to have no border no bottom margin no padding and I still get this white space.

Can anyone figure out what I can do to get rid of it.

The site is at http://www.joekellywebdesign.com/churchsample/home.html.

Comment: You mean between the banner and the content?  The white horiz strip?

Comment: setting `font-size: 0;` to the wrapper eliminates the gap between the banner and the content. maybe it will help someone understand the cause..

Comment: Also, it looks right in quirks mode, albeit not centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are talking about white space between #banner and #content this is the solution

add overflow:hidden; for #wrapper and

```
#footer {
    float: left;
    height: 79px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 900px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about the `#wrapper` div it has `margin: 10px auto`.  The first one is the top margin (10px).  The `<p>` inside the footer div also has default margins that you need to remove.

Answer (score 1):

feww, took me a while to figure-it-out.

If you're taking about the space between `#banner` and `#content`,
the gap is caused due to your floating elements, the `p` is not floating, and not clearing, so it just a regular block element who's content need to 'flow' beside floating elements.
causing the `p` to 'swallow' your floating div's, then he's default margin/padding kicks in, causing the whole thing to move.

the fix is very easy, just add this to your **CSS**.

```
#footer p
{
    clear: both;
}
```